# When will the docusign api implement CORS or JSONP?

Tags: docusignapi

My company is building a browser-javascript app. We want to use the docusign api via browser javascript without using a proxy server (our clients really don't like paying for extra proxy servers). So if you can implement CORS or JSONP for your api, it will be much easier for us to convince our clients to purchase and use docusign. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking speculation as to when software (DocuSign) will implement certain features.

Comment: Ehm, you confused the question box with docusign's contact form, didn't you?

Comment: I have actually contacted Docusign already and they assure me this is the right way to get a hold of their development team. I had doubts myself and knew better than to post this on stackoverflow without checking first. But I guess I got played. I will rephrase the question in a more "proper" form then.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign does not support CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) in its platform. There are too many potential security risks with CORS and for DocuSign to maintain its extremely high level of security and certification compliance it can not support CORS.